# Action Script 3. 30 times use one image and 6 times other

Tags: image, actionscript-3, flash, class, actionscript

Ok, I'm creating flash memory game. In this game you need to find 2 equal card and discover them. At all here are 36 cards (6x6).

I have 2 different images for card when It spawns. 1.png I need to use 30 times and 2.png I need to use 6 times.
Example(where is stars should be 2.png):

[image: img example]

Is it possible?

Here is my Card.as Movie Clip

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Card extends MovieClip
    {
        public var _type:*;

        public function Card()
        {
            this.buttonMode = true;
            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
        }

        private function onClick(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if(this.currentFrame == 1)
            {
                this.play();
            }
        }

        public function setType(type:*):void
        {
            _type = type;
            loader_mc.addChild(_type);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: What does loader_mc look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After loading your files using Loader or URLLoader you need to convert your loaded content into reusable object.

```
private var starsVec:Vector.<Bitmap >  = new Vector.<Bitmap >   ;
private var starBitmapData:BitmapData;

public function shiiiit()
{
    var loader:Loader = new Loader  ;
    var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("plik.png");
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onLoaded);
    loader.load(url);
}

private function onLoaded(e:Event):void
{
    //saves loaded graphic file into BitmapData object
    starBitmapData = new BitmapData(e.target.content.width,e.target.content.height,true,0);
    starBitmapData.draw(e.target.content);
    createTable();
}

private function createTable():void
{
    for (var i:uint=0; i<6; i++)
    {
        //now use BitmapData object to create new Bitmap object and add it to stage
        starsVec.push(new Bitmap(starBitmapData));
        var starsVecTopElem:Bitmap = starsVec[starsVec.length - 1];
        addChild(starsVecTopElem);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's even easier: If you load a PNG, the `content` is of type `Bitmap`, you are able to do `starBitmapData=e.target.content.bitmapdata;` and that's all.